# How to Downgrade my android application?

Tags: android

In my application i need to run my application of both versions android 2.1 and android 2.2. my application run sucessfully in android 2.2 but it shows error "DTD handler not supported" when i run on 2.1. My build is made in 2.1,but this application only run in 
its a web application and i am using sax parser.
please suggest what should to do. its urgent
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your project, choose Properties, then click Android and check which version you are using.

Also check your Manifest.xml to see if the following line is present

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
```

This should map to the correct version you want. For 2.0 its 5, 7 fro 2.1 and for 2.2 its 8

Answer (score 0):

IN ECLIPSE:

```
Right Click your project folder.
  Select Properties
    Select Android in the left Pane
      Select your build target

 Select Project from the top menu
   Select Clean, clean your project

BULID and RUN
```

Comment: thax, i solved it,i tried these but i found problem in my saxparser.

Comment: what was the problem in your saxparser? because in my saxparser, parserfactory.setValidating(true) gives exception. This method works in java but not in android. In android it works only when i set validation to false. i.e. setValidating(false). Can you give any idea, how can I give DTD validation in android?